# Как убрать упоминания файла из Windows 7 после удаления из корзины?

Tags: windows, windows-7

Удалил файл с Windows 7 способом:
Нажал удалить (файл переместился в корзину)
Очистил корзину

Но если искать его в поиске через пуск, он находит название этого файла, но открыть его уже не удается.

Как сделать, чтобы файл не находился через поиск?

Comment: У Вас Windows 10?

Comment: Лезть в реестр и чистить упоминание о нём во всех MRU. Впрочем, это не уберёт его из кэшей и файловых логов разных приложений.

Comment: Исправил, у меня windows 7

Comment: @Akina А как удалить только из кэша приложения, которое используется для поиска в windiws 7?

Comment: Странное поведение ОС. В первый раз о таком слышу. Только специально повторил Ваши действия - все удалилось, ничего в поиске не находится. ОС лицензия? Или сборка "зверская" какая-нибудь?

Answer (score 0):

CCleaner'ом почистите комп и реестр)

Скачать можете тут: https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download/standard